# PhpSpreadsheet with large data

Tags: php, excel, large-data, phpspreadsheet

i have a multidimensional array with 3070 Values

```
$tbl= array(
  array(
    "KDNR" => 1,
    "GESCHL" => "test",
    "TITEL" => "test",
    "VORNAME" => "test",
    "FAMNAME" => "test",
    "PLZ" => "test",
    "ORT" => "test",
    "STRASSE" => "test",
    "EMAIL" => "test",
    "PRIVTEL" => "test"
  ),
  "KDNR" => 2,
    "GESCHL" => "test2",
    "TITEL" => "test2",
    "VORNAME" => "test2",
    "FAMNAME" => "test2",
    "PLZ" => "test2",
    "ORT" => "test2",
    "STRASSE" => "test2",
    "EMAIL" => "test2",
    "PRIVTEL" => "test2"
  ),
  etc...
);
```

I want to write the array tbl with 3070 arrays to a xlsx file.
I use for this PhpSpreadsheet.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
//call the autoload
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php');
//load phpspreadsheet class using namespaces
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
//call iofactory instead of xlsx writer
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Aligment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;


//load from xlsx template
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/src/ExcelVorlagen/polbezirk_template.xlsx');

//loop the data
$contentStartRow = 3;
$currentContenRow = 3;

//set coulm dimension to auto size
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('A')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('B')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('C')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('D')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('E')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('F')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('G')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('H')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('I')
            ->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension('J')
            ->setAutoSize(true);

xdebug_break();
foreach($tbl as $item){
    //insert a row after current row (before current row + 1)
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($currentContenRow + 1,1);

    //fill the cell with Data
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A'.$currentContenRow, $item['KDNR'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$currentContenRow, $item['GESCHL'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$currentContenRow, $item['TITEL'])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$currentContenRow, $item['VORNAME'])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$currentContenRow, $item['FAMNAME'])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$currentContenRow, $item['PLZ'])
        ->setCellValue('G'.$currentContenRow, $item['ORT'])
        ->setCellValue('H'.$currentContenRow, $item['STRASSE'])
        ->setCellValue('I'.$currentContenRow, $item['EMAIL'])
        ->setCellValue('J'.$currentContenRow, $item['PRIVTEL']);
    //increment the current row number
    $currentContenRow++;                 
}

//remove last empty rows
//$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($currentContenRow,2); 

//set the header first, so the result will be treated as an xlsx file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

//make it an attachment so we can define filename
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx"');

//create IOFactory object
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
//save int php output
$writer->save('php://output');
```

when i execute the code it takes 49 minutes to create the xlsx file, this it to long for only 3070 rows.
Is there a faster way? Or have i a bottleneck in my code?

hope you guys can help me

best best regards

Comment: Does it help to store $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet() in a variable and reference this variable instead of calling the method over and over?

Comment: And if you know how many rows you are going to add, use that as the second parameter of `insertNewRow` and call the method only once: https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_insertNewColumnBefore

Answer (score 2):

thank you very much kalyfe,
i modified my code like this:

```
$row = count($tbl);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($currentContenRow + 1, $row);

foreach($tbl as $item){
    //fill the cell with Data
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A'.$currentContenRow, $item['KDNR'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$currentContenRow, $item['GESCHL'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$currentContenRow, $item['TITEL'])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$currentContenRow, $item['VORNAME'])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$currentContenRow, $item['FAMNAME'])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$currentContenRow, $item['PLZ'])
        ->setCellValue('G'.$currentContenRow, $item['ORT'])
        ->setCellValue('H'.$currentContenRow, $item['STRASSE'])
        ->setCellValue('I'.$currentContenRow, $item['EMAIL'])
        ->setCellValue('J'.$currentContenRow, $item['PRIVTEL']);
    //increment the current row number
    $currentContenRow++;                 
}
```

now it takes 15sec for creating the xlsx file

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to do a similar job, and thought it might be worth sharing, it might help someone.

The code takes your original array (`$tbl`), and reformats it (injects a column header `record` at the start of the array) so the data is formatted properly for PhpSpreadsheet to process and write to a `.xlsx` file.

The function used to process the data: `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray()` (see below).

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

require dirname(__DIR__, 1) . "/vendor/autoload.php";

// the original array
$tbl = [
    [
    "KDNR" => 1,
    "GESCHL" => "test",
    "TITEL" => "test",
    "VORNAME" => "test",
    "FAMNAME" => "test",
    "PLZ" => "test",
    "ORT" => "test",
    "STRASSE" => "test",
    "EMAIL" => "test",
    "PRIVTEL" => "test"
    ],
    [
    "KDNR" => 2,
    "GESCHL" => "test2",
    "TITEL" => "test2",
    "VORNAME" => "test2",
    "FAMNAME" => "test2",
    "PLZ" => "test2",
    "ORT" => "test2",
    "STRASSE" => "test2",
    "EMAIL" => "test2",
    "PRIVTEL" => "test2"
    ],
];

/*
 * inject header 'record'.
 */
$headers = array_keys($tbl[0]); // get headers from source array
array_unshift($tbl, $headers); // insert headers as first record

/*
 * write data to xlsx file
 */
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
// build spreadsheet from array
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($tbl,
    NULL, // array values with this value will not be set
    'A1');

// write array data to xlsx file
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('yourfile.xlsx');
```

The reshuffled `$tbl` array, ready to be processed by `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray()`, looks as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => KDNR
            [1] => GESCHL
            [2] => TITEL
            [3] => VORNAME
            [4] => FAMNAME
            [5] => PLZ
            [6] => ORT
            [7] => STRASSE
            [8] => EMAIL
            [9] => PRIVTEL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [KDNR] => 1
            [GESCHL] => test
            [TITEL] => test
            [VORNAME] => test
            [FAMNAME] => test
            [PLZ] => test
            [ORT] => test
            [STRASSE] => test
            [EMAIL] => test
            [PRIVTEL] => test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [KDNR] => 2
            [GESCHL] => test2
            [TITEL] => test2
            [VORNAME] => test2
            [FAMNAME] => test2
            [PLZ] => test2
            [ORT] => test2
            [STRASSE] => test2
            [EMAIL] => test2
            [PRIVTEL] => test2
        )

)
```

The first record will be used to set column headers, the following records are the row data.

The resulting xlsx file:
[image]