# PhpSpreadsheet: Algorithm using nested loops to populate spreadsheet never reaches last iteration of outermost loop

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpSpreadsheet to populate a spreadsheet using a multi-tiered associative array returned as a result set from a MySQL query. The array looks as follows:

```
callStats [
    [1]=>array[
        ['op']=>7558,
        ['option']=>'Claim',
        ['c']=>'7'
    ]
    [2]=>array[
        //Same structure at every index in outermost array
    ]
]
```

I am using two separate arrays to populate column headers (with op) and column row identifiers (with options).

What I want to do is populate a matrix whereby every permutation of op & option is populated with the correct count('c') being the number of times a given op has chosen a given option.

Everything is working fine until the last row of possible options, at which point the loop I am using moves to the next column and begins iterating again from the beginning, even though there should be a final row populated in each column. [Spreadsheet example with missing bottiom row in each column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC9vv.png)

The code I am using to build the spreadsheet and populate cells is as follows:

```
// Arrange operator columns
    $col = 'C';
    $row = 2;
    for($i=0;$i<=count($operatorResult)-1;$i++) {
        $this->sheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
        $this->sheet->setCellValue($col.$row, $operatorResult[$i]['op']);
        $col++;
    }

    // Arrange options columns
    $optionsCol = 'B';
    $optionsRow = 3;
    for($i=0;$i<=count($optionsResult)-1;$i++) {
        $this->sheet->setCellValue($optionsCol.$optionsRow, $optionsResult[$i]['option']);
        $optionsRow++;
    }

    // Plot statistics matrix
    $letter = 'C';
    $columnCounter = 3;
    $rowCounter = 3;
    foreach($this->result as $data) {

            if($data['op'] === (string)$this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($columnCounter, 2)->getValue()) {

                if ($data['option'] !== $this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $rowCounter)->getValue()) {
                    $this->sheet->setCellValue($letter.$rowCounter, '0');
                    $rowCounter++;
                }

                $this->sheet->setCellValue($letter.$rowCounter, $data['c']);
                $rowCounter++;

                // Move to the next column once you reach a blank cell in the options column
                if($this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, ($rowCounter+1))->getValue() === null) {

                    // Move over a column
                    $letter++;
                    $columnCounter++;
                    // Go back to the first row of options
                    $rowCounter = 3;
                }
            }
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how or why the algorithm will not populate the final option row for the corresponding op columns, i.e the very bottom row will not populate, when logically it should.

The reason I have not used PhpSpreadsheet's built-in fromArray() function to build the matrix is because fromArray() interprets the first index of each array as a column header(if I am interpreting the documentation correctly), which I definitely do not want. This would result in repeated column headers, as the same op appears multiple times in different permutations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use foreach for both loops?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880863/phpspreadsheet-with-large-data/59887890#59887890) might help. It explains how to use `fromArray()`, setting the headers in the first record, and the following records are data only.